# How to make RigidBody 2D Jump on specific XYZ Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been googling for like a week, but i still haven't found a thing. What i need is that the `Character(Cat)` has to jump on platform, after x clicks on this platform. There are no movements, only auto jump.

This thing is the last thing that should be done.

Comment: The question is not very clear. Try adding some of your code.

Comment: @ReazMurshed
if only i could. I will try to explain better with [picture](http://prntscr.com/b7z5ob)
So there is a Cat and there is a platform. The point is that Cat has to jump on this platform, when Player clicks on this platform. Its like Click to Move like in some MMORPGs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed your comment, saying you wanted it like in rpgs where you click a position, then your toon moves there. If that is similar to what you want, there's a few different ways you can do it. You could do something like

```
public GameObject cat;
int clickedAmount = 5;

OnMouseDown() {
   clickedAmount -= 1;
   if (clickedAmount <= 0){
       cat.GetComponent<CatControllerScript>().moveToTarget = transform; //Give the cat script the transform of this platform
   } 
}
```

Then in the cat script do something like

```
public Transform moveToTarget;
public float moveSpeed;
void Update(){
    if (moveToTarget != null){
        //one way is
       transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, moveToTarget.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        //Another way is 
        transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, moveToTarget.position,  moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }}
```

Then one you can check the collisions, and if you collide with the transform, make the moveToTarget = null. Or you can make a bool that is changed, and then just pass the transform seperately.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Will try this tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, let me know how it turns out! :D

Comment: Thanks, man! That's what i have been looking for weeks! Bless you :'D

Comment: No problem, could you do me a favor and upvote and mark it as the answe? Id appreciate it haha

Answer (score 1):

You can make the cat jump by adding velocity to its rigidbody.
As for clicking the platform, add a Box Collider 2D to it. Then add this script to the platform.

```
//after the using statements
public GameObject cat; //set this in the inspector by dragging the cat into the variable slot
int clickedAmount = 5;//times it takes to click before the cat jumps
float jumpForce = 10.0f

OnMouseDown() {
    clickedAmount -= 1
    if (clickedAmount == 0) {
         cat.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f,jumpForce));
    }
}
```

If the cat doesn't appear to jump, make sure you increase the `jumpForce` variable.